# NodeJS: освободить память, занимаемую объектом или пометить объект на удаление для сборщика мусора

Tags: node.js, сборщик-мусора

В общем то вопрос прямо в заголовке. Разобью на два варианта, чтобы более чётко копнуть в вопрос:

1) Можно ли каким-либо образом деструктурировать объект, освободив занимаемую им память?

2) Можно ли каким-либо образом пометить объект на удаление так, чтобы память, занимаемая им, была полностью освобождена при следующем запуске сборщика мусора вне зависимости от того, есть на этот объект ссылочный путь от глобального объекта, или нет?

Стандартные средства найти не могу. Возможно, существуют какие-то библиотеки/модули/классы и т.п.

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/oleg-bunin/blog/433318/ - возможно поможет

Answer (score 1):

Нужно просто удалить все ссылки на объект, т.е. явно занулить `x = null;`. Либо добиться автоматического освобождения путём оптимизации скоупов, т.е. не делать долгоживущих функций, стремиться к чистым функциям вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Берешь и удаляешь
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Но будь осторожен с этим, чтоб не нарваться случайно на удаленные тобой же свойтсва :)

А вообще, лучше просто внимательно смотреть какие обьекты где используются, своевременно зануливать если очень нужно. Возможно у тебя где-то утечка, попробуй просто по-профайлить.

Comment: Буду признателен, если подскажешь средство диагностики утечек. Мне бы такое, чтобы еще и зависшие сущности показал. Хотя бы названия.

Comment: Какой-то костыльный совет...

Comment: @Lex профайлер хрома наше все